# Orika fails only in "mvn clean install", but works from IDE or single test run

Tags: java, orika

I run today into a specific problem, when I run **mvn clean install** on my project it fails on the number of tests with the following message:

```
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 12, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.709 sec <<< FAILURE! - in my.domain.service.registration.packaging.PackagingServiceIntegrationTest
shouldPerformChangeAndReviewAfterAddForShelfLife(my.domain.service.registration.packaging.PackagingServiceIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.406 sec  <<< ERROR!
ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: Error encountered while mapping for the following inputs: 
rawSource=my.domain.model.registration.status.PackagingEntry@10c107e8
sourceClass=class my.domain.model.registration.status.PackagingEntry
destinationClass=class my.domain.model.draft.registration.status.PackagingEntryDraft
    at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Country_ObjectFactory1309247994232113101825346964$16.create(Country_ObjectFactory1309247994232113101825346964$16.java)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.getInstance(InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.java:36)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:46)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:136)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_AdjustRegProduct_AdjustRegProduct_Mapper13424360330059$22.mapAtoB(Orika_AdjustRegProduct_AdjustRegProduct_Mapper13424360330059$22.java)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy$ForwardMapperReference.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:74)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:50)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:136)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_License_License_Mapper13424295393133$21.mapAtoB(Orika_License_License_Mapper13424295393133$21.java)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy$ForwardMapperReference.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:74)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:50)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:136)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_PackagingEntryDraft_PackagingEntry_Mapper13424250032621$20.mapAtoB(Orika_PackagingEntryDraft_PackagingEntry_Mapper13424250032621$20.java)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy$ForwardMapperReference.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:74)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:50)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:676)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:656)
    at my.domain.dto.utils.OrikaConverter.convert(OrikaConverter.java:30)
```

But when I run it from IntelliJ or using

```
mvn clean -Dtest=PackagingServiceIntegrationTest
```

it passes correctly.

I'm using orika 1.4.1, do you have any idea about what might be the cause?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?